# Checking a column value when updating a gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to do some error handling on a column to see if it's not equal to a certain word. I'm wondering though do i do this on the RowUpdating event or the RowUpdated event. I've been trying to do this in the rowupdating event and haven't had any luck so far. Here's the code.

```
      TableCell cell = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3];

        if(cell.Text == "hello")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        lblError.Text = "hello" + cell.Text;
```

I assume the 3 after inside the brackets after .Cells is the column index that I want. If i use .Cells[1] it will show the primary key no in the label, but if I try 2 or 3 nothing seems to be getting placed inside the cell variable.
My table has four columns, ID, Name, Price, and CategoryID. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `RowUpdating` is before the row is actually updated. `RowUpdated` occurs after. Try putting a break point in your code and seeing what the values are in the GridView1.

Comment: It seems to be only returning the first column, which is the primary key, because it is read only. The textboxes where i'm updating the data aren't being seen as values for the GridView

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and look at the properties of GridView1? You can see the current contents and that should tell you something about your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get the input box values, you will have to find the control like:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
string price = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
```

You can also check against the e.NewValues.

And fyi: You will have to set the e.Cancel=true, if you want to cancel the event upon meeting certain condition(s).

Check [RowUpdatingEvent ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).